# How to select a face created with edges?

Tags: modeling

I created a mesh with Cell Fractured. I then cleaned it up adding \ removing edges , vertices, faces. But now I have these black lines when I'm out of edit mode. What does it mean and how come I don't see the black edges across the entire mesh?

Also when I try to select each individual "triangle" I can't .. it selects the entire face. I tried removing doubles, but it doesn't fix it.

[image]

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've attached it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Adam gives your the right answer, you have big ngons faces and edges that are not associate with these faces, so you need to delete those faces and recreate some faces between your edges.

Comment: Yea I'd give him an "answer" tick, but my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 3):

Those black lines are edges which are co-planar to that face, but not associated with it. If you select those edges, they can be deleted without deleting the face. If you want to select those face sections individually, you'll have to remake them first. Start by deleting the face. Then select the edges (or verts) around *one* of the desired faces, then press 'F' to generate a new face there. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ooh. That's strange that Blender would do that. I'm used to 3dsmax's workflow where it'd automatically become individual faces upon adding new edges in between old faces. Thanks for the help.